# How can I make two threads to do two different loops or methods?

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm

I have a algorithm to calculate something in a grid looking very roughly like this:

```java
public class Main {

    pass1 ;
    pass2 ;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Function f = new Function();
        f.solve(pass1, pass2);
    }
}

public class Function {

    public void solve(pass1, pass2) {
        method1(pass1, pass2);
        method2(pass1, pass2);
        method3(pass1, pass2);
    }
    method1(pass1, pass2) {
        //parse grid
        for (row = 0; row < numofrows; row++) {
            for (col = 0; col < numofcols; col++) {
                method4(stuff in here to pass);
                       }
                   }
               }
                  method2(pass1, pass2) {
        //parse grid
        for (row = 0; row < numofrows; row++) {
            for (col = 0; col < numofcols; col++) {
                method4(stuff in here to pass );
                       }
                   }
               }
                  method3(pass1, pass2) {
        //do stuff
    }

    method4(stuff) {
        //add object to hashmap
    }
}
```

I want to make the algorithm faster using Threads.

The idea that I have is to make one thread do method1 and/or method2 with a even increment counter, and another thread to do it in an odd increment counter, making use of more cpu, because right now it's only using 25% (1/4 cores I assume).

Is it possible to make a thread do a different loop or method if I were to make `method2even()` and `method2odd()`? If so how would I implement this, I have been trying for hours and I can't wrap my head around it...

Comment: Separate the logic into separate classes, implementing the `Callable` interface and go for it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're suggesting is fine-grained parallelism, which can cause problems because of the memory hierarchy - if two threads are operating on alternating indices of the same array/matrix then they're going to have to essentially write directly to main memory (e.g. by flushing their caches after every operation) which is probably going to cause your multi-threaded program to run considerably slower than your single-threaded program.  As much as possible, try to have your threads write to completely different segments of memory, e.g. entirely different arrays/matrices or at least different sections of the same array/matrix (e.g. thread1 writes to the first half of an array while thread2 writes to the second half - hopefully their array segments will be on different cache lines and they won't need to write to main memory to maintain coherency); if your threads are operating on the same memory segments then try to have them do so at different times, so that they can calculate their intermediate results in cache prior to flushing their final results to main memory.

So in your case, are `method1`, `method2`, and `method3` independent of each other?  If so then use a different thread for each method.  If they're not independent, e.g. `method1` must precede `method2` must precede `method3`, then you could use a pipeline approach: Thread1 executes `method1` on the first N elements of the matrix, then Thread2 executes `method2` on the first N elements of the matrix while Thread1 executes `method1` on the second N elements of the matrix, then Thread3 executes `method3` on the first N elements of the matrix while Thread2 executes `method2` on the second N elements of the matrix while Thread1 executes `method1` on the first N elements of the matrix, and so on until all matrix elements have been processed.

If your threads need to talk to each other (e.g. to pass around matrix segments for pipelining) then I prefer to use something like a [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html): Method1 and Method2 would share a queue, with Method1 writing elements to it (via `offer`) and Method2 reading elements from it (via `take`).  Method2 blocks with `take` until Method1 sends it a matrix segment to work on, then when Method2 is finished with the matrix segment it will send it on to Method3 via another BlockingQueue, then calls `take` again on the queue it shares with Method1.

---

Assuming that your methods are independent, some code to run them on separate threads would be as follows; this can be modified to accommodate pipelining instead.  I'm omitting the MethodN constructors where you'll need to pass in the matrix etc.  I'm using the [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) interface, but as MadProgrammer said in the comments you can use [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) instead.  The [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) is responsible for assigning the Runnables to threads.

```
public class Method1 implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
       // execute method1
    }
}

public class Method2 implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
       // execute method2
    }
}

public class Method3 implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
       // execute method3
    }
}

public class Function {
    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

    public void solve(pass1, pass2) {
        Method1 method1 = new Method1(pass1, pass2);
        Method2 method2 = new Method2(pass1, pass2);
        Method3 method3 = new Method3(pass1, pass2);
        executor.submit(method1);
        executor.submit(method2);
        executor.submit(method3);
    }
}
```